# This is a canadian mathematic olympiad question

Tags: number-theory

Let n be a positive integer, and define $S_{n} = \{1,2,...,n\}.$ Consider a non-empty subset $T$ of $S_{n}$. We say that $T$ is balanced if the median of $T$ is equal to the average of $T$. For example, for $n = 9$, each of the subsets $\{7\}, \{2,5\}, \{2,3,4\}, \{5,6,8,9\}, \text{ and }\{1,4,5,7,8\}$ is balanced; however, the subsets $\{2,4,5\}$ and $\{1,2,3,5\}$ are not balanced. For each $n \geq 1$, prove that the number of balanced subsets of $S_{n}$ is odd. (To define the median of a set of $k$ numbers, first put the numbers in increasing order; then the median is the middle number if $k$ is odd, and the average of the two middle numbers if $k$ is even. For example, the median of $\{1,3,4,8,9\}$ is $4$, and the median of $\{1,3,4,7,8,9\}$ is $(4 +7)/2 = 5.5.)$

Comment: Have you tried induction? The base case is clear enough, and then all you have to show is that, for $n>1$, the number of balanced subsets of $S_n$ containing the number $n$ is even.

Comment: can you please give abit more detailed answer

Comment: I haven't got a solution. I'm just giving a suggestion of something that might work.

Comment: Have you tried induction? What have you tried?

Comment: Another approach might be to show that the number of non-balanced subsets is even, because the total number of non-empty subsets is odd, and odd - even = odd.

Comment: well we need to prove that there are odd subsets and induction dosent works

Comment: Yeah, I edited my comment. The second approach will work, and I'm typing up an answer now.

Comment: You can also get the solutions here: https://cms.math.ca/Competitions/OMC/

Answer (score 3):

Consider the map $f:\mathcal{P}(S_n)\to\mathcal{P}(S_n)$ that takes a subset $T$ and replaces every number $k\in T$ with $n+1-k$. In other words, it's a reversal map. In $S_9$, we have $f(\{1,2,4\}) = \{9,8,6\}$.

This function has the property that it takes unbalanced sets to unbalanced sets, and balanced sets to balanced sets. Also, if $T$ is unbalanced, then $f(T)\ne T$. Thus, the unbalanced subsets are partitioned into pairs, so they are even in number.

Comment: thanks alot for the help

Comment: You might need to provide a little justification for the claim $f(T)\ne T$ for unbalanced $T$. I'd probably do that by contrapositive.